# Pythonic way to create union of all values contained in multiple lists

Tags: python, list, set-union

I have a list of lists:

```
lists = [[1,4,3,2,4], [4,5]]
```

I want to flatten this list and remove all duplicates; or, in other words, apply a set union operation:

```
desired_result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

[`set.union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) does what you want:

```
>>> results_list = [[1,2,3], [1,2,4]]
>>> results_union = set().union(*results_list)
>>> print(results_union)
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

You can also do this with more than two lists.

Comment: @sth, thanks for example, but when I run it I get an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so_example.py", line 33, in ?
    results_union=set().union(*result_lists)
TypeError: union() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

Comment: @AJ: According to the documentsion (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) `union()` only supports multiple arguments for Python version 2.6 or higher. You seem to use a version before that, so you probably have to use an explicit loop: `total = set(); for x in results_list: total.update(x)` *(s/;/\n/)*

Comment: You can also save creating an empty set by changing the 2nd line to `results_union = set.union(*(set(el) for el in results_list))`

Comment: In this case it's less neat. But if the inputs on the first line were sets too...

Comment: I'm just adding this as I found it useful to know how to union a bunch of sets at once

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Wrong.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `TypeError: descriptor 'union' requires a 'set' object but received a 'list'` in python 3.6 atleast.

Comment: If you use `set.union(*results_list)` you're binding the method descriptor manually, i.e. sending in the first element of `results_list` as "self". This makes some weird restrictions: 1. doesn't duck-type properly (now the first element must be a set or instance of a set subclass), and 2. union of an empty `results_list` will be an error (incorrect result - should return empty set).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Which version of python did you test it on successfully? I tried both 2.7 and 3.6 and got errors on both.

Comment: sorry, actually I had a list of `set`s in input. Which explains why it worked for me, because first argument was used as `self`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 18):

Since you seem to be using Python 2.5 (it **would** be nice to mention in your Q if you need an A for versions != 2.6, the current production one, by the way;-) and want a list rather than a set as the result, I recommend:

```
import itertools

...

return list(set(itertools.chain(*result_list)))
```

[itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools) is generally a great way to work with iterators (and so with many kinds of sequences or collections) and I heartily recommend you become familiar with it.  `itertools.chain`, in particular, is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.chain).

Comment: +1 A perfect example of a good time to dip into the wonderful `itertools` package.

Comment: @Alex thanks...edited my question to specify version and remove blame from myself for being so behind in versions :)  I'll make it a point to look into itertools, appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @AJ, no blame, we all can suffer under such constraints after all (but please do remember to specify in future Qs!-); `itertools.chain` works fine in Python 2.4 as well, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You can also follow this style

```
In [12]: a = ['Orange and Banana', 'Orange Banana']
In [13]: b = ['Grapes', 'Orange Banana']
In [14]: c = ['Foobanana', 'Orange and Banana']

In [20]: list(set(a) | set(b) | set(c))
Out[20]: ['Orange and Banana', 'Foobanana', 'Orange Banana', 'Grapes']

In [21]: list(set(a) & set(b) | set(c))
Out[21]: ['Orange and Banana', 'Foobanana', 'Orange Banana']
```

Answer (score 3):

in comprehension way:

```py
[*{ j for i in lists for j in i }]
```

or

```py
[*functools.reduce(lambda x,y: {*x, *y}, lists)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Unions are not supported by lists, which are ordered, but are supported by sets. Check out [set.union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Answer (score 0):

I  used the following to do intersections, which avoids the need for sets.

```
a, b= [[1,2,3], [1,2]]
s = filter( lambda x: x in b, a)
```

or,

```
s = [ x for x in b if x in a ]
```

Comment: Why would you even want to "avoid the need for sets"?  They're faster, and clearer, for this purpose.  And your "x in a" does a linear, brute-force search through the list each time you execute it.  Yuck.

Comment: sets require type casting, and linear speed isn't bad unless you are dealing with a large N.

Comment: "Type casting"?  In Python?  Since when?  Sets are basically dicts with only the keys, and they use hash and equality comparisons.  Using "x in a" on a list does an equality comparison too.  What's all this about type casting?

Answer (score -2):

```
desired_result = [x for y in lists for x in y]
```