# What is the preferred way to compose a set from multiple lists in Python

Tags: python

I have a few different lists that I want to turn into a set and use to find the difference from another set. Let's call them A, B, and C.

Is the more optimal way to do this `set(A + B + C)` or `set(A).union(set(B)).union(set(C))`

Would certain properties of A, B, and C like the number of duplicates or length affect this decision?

Would having an arbitrary number of sets?

Comment: I don't think you can use + for adding sets

Comment: There are various ideas over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151517/pythonic-way-to-create-union-of-all-values-contained-in-multiple-lists

Comment: Ah good catch I will update my question -- I incorrectly assumed `+` would perform a set union behind the scenes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For small lists, `set(A + B + C)` works fine. For larger lists, the following is more efficient because it does not create a temporary list:

```
myset = set(A)
myset.update(B)
myset.update(C)
```

A different approach uses `itertools.chain`, which is also efficient because it does not create temporary list:

```
import itertools
myset = set(itertools.chain(A, B, C))
```

Comment: Actually, it turns out that `itertools.chain` is not much faster than `A+B+C` in this case, even for 10000-element lists (timing data: `A+B+C` 2.33ms, `update` 2.09ms, `chain` 2.23ms)

Comment: Results are weird, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483539/why-is-creating-a-set-from-a-concatenated-list-faster-than-using-update - `A+B+C` is actually faster for large lists...

Answer (score 3):

Here is some timing experiments:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

for r in [10,100,1000,10000]:
   A = list(np.random.randint(r, size=1000000))
   B = list(np.random.randint(r, size=1000000))

   %timeit set(A).update(B)
   %timeit set(A+B)
   %timeit set(itertools.chain(A, B))
   print('---')
```

Here is the results for `size = 1000`:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.2 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.3 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 90.7 µs per loop
---
10000 loops, best of 3: 88.2 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 86.8 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 89.4 µs per loop
---
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.9 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.5 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 87 µs per loop
---
10000 loops, best of 3: 97.4 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 102 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 107 µs per loop
```

Here is the results for `size = 1000000`:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 89 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 106 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 98.4 ms per loop
---
10 loops, best of 3: 89.1 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 110 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 94.2 ms per loop
---
10 loops, best of 3: 94.9 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop
---
10 loops, best of 3: 115 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 143 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 138 ms per loop
```

So, `update()` seems to be slightly faster than both other methods. However, I don't think that the time difference is significant.

Comment: Time Hai Vu's `itertools.chain` approach too.

Comment: Thank you for doing some timing test.

Comment: Thank you for timing these, I haven't seen %timeit before. Would you mind adding one more for `set(A).union(set(B))`? I'm wondering how it compares to update.