# Why is creating a set from a concatenated list faster than using `.update`?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, set

While trying to answer [What is the preferred way to compose a set from multiple lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482722/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-compose-a-set-from-multiple-lists-in-python/32483214), I did some performance analysis and came up with a somewhat surprising conclusion.

Using

```
python -m timeit -s '
import itertools
import random
n=1000000
random.seed(0)
A = [random.randrange(1<<30) for _ in xrange(n)]
B = [random.randrange(1<<30) for _ in xrange(n)]
C = [random.randrange(1<<30) for _ in xrange(n)]'
```

for setup, I timed the following snippets:

```
> $TIMEIT 'set(A+B+C)'
10 loops, best of 3: 872 msec per loop

> $TIMEIT 's = set(A); s.update(B); s.update(C)'
10 loops, best of 3: 930 msec per loop

> $TIMEIT 's = set(itertools.chain(A,B,C))'
10 loops, best of 3: 941 msec per loop
```

To my surprise, `set(A+B+C)` is the *fastest* despite the fact that it creates an intermediate list containing 3000000 elements. `.update` and `itertools.chain` are both slower, even though neither of them copy any lists.

What's going on here?

---

EDIT: On a second machine (OS X 10.10.5, Python 2.7.10, 2.5GHz Core i7), I ran the following script (which runs the tests forwards and backwards to avoid ordering effects):

```
SETUP='import itertools
import random
n=1000000
random.seed(0)
A = [random.randrange(1<<30) for _ in xrange(n)]
B = [random.randrange(1<<30) for _ in xrange(n)]
C = [random.randrange(1<<30) for _ in xrange(n)]'

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" 'set(A+B+C)'
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" 's = set(A); s.update(B); s.update(C)'
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" 's = set(itertools.chain(A,B,C))'

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" 's = set(itertools.chain(A,B,C))'
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" 's = set(A); s.update(B); s.update(C)'
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" 'set(A+B+C)'
```

and obtained the following results:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 579 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 726 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 775 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 761 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 737 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 555 msec per loop
```

Now `set(A+B+C)` is *clearly* faster, and the results are quite stable - it is hard to chalk this up to mere measurement error. Running this script repeatedly produces similar results.

Comment: The only guess I can make is that the first case passes in a list which has a known length, and so perhaps the set construction can more sensibly choose the initial underlying memory requirement, as opposed to the other two where the set is created and resized twice (second case) or created with an iterator where it potentially resizes internally many times.

Comment: Unless they changed `set_init`, that's not how it seems to work. [`set_init`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/setobject.c) just calls straight to `set_update_internal` which just loops over the elements. (I'd pull from `hg.python.org` but that server seems down at the moment)

Comment: related: [Combining two sorted lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/482848/4279)

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python 2.7 on OS X; all three tests show quite some variation, and none of them are clear winners. With only 10 repeats and a very long running time (~8 seconds for 10 tests) you capture a lot of noise.

Comment: When I lower `n` to 1000, and repeat 10k times, the `set.update()` version wins reasonably consistently.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: [the results are mixed on my machine (Ubuntu) and on travis on various Python versions](https://github.com/zed/test-performance-create-set-from-3-lists) e.g., [`set(A+B+C)` is faster on pypy](https://travis-ci.org/zed/test-performance-create-set-from-3-lists/jobs/79507967), while [`set(A).update(B, C)` might be slightly faster on CPython 2.7](https://travis-ci.org/zed/test-performance-create-set-from-3-lists/jobs/79507962)

Comment: Travis suggests that `A+B+C` is slower by a bit, although it is interesting that it is much faster on PyPy. Also, I forgot that you can do `set(A).update(B, C)`, that's useful.

Comment: This is what I see on 2.7.10 when running everything in the same interpreter session: https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/0ede53140a04f8198e90; `set.update()` is marginally faster.

Answer (score 0):

I get different, non-surprising, results than you on my Win 7 SP1 box with a similar processor with Python 2.7.10, where `set(A+B+C)` appears to be the *slowest* way to do it as one might expect. Similar results were obtained with garbage collection re-enabled and with Python 3.4.3.

I used my own performance assessing testbed based on `timeit` and got the following results:

```
fastest to slowest execution speeds (Python 2.7.10)
   (10 executions, best of 3 repetitions)

set(A); s.update(B); s.update(C) :  4.787919 secs, rel speed 1.00x,  0.00% slower
              set(A).update(B,C) :  6.463666 secs, rel speed 1.35x, 35.00% slower
     set(itertools.chain(A,B,C)) :  6.743028 secs, rel speed 1.41x, 40.83% slower
                      set(A+B+C) :  8.030483 secs, rel speed 1.68x, 67.72% slower
```

Benchmarking code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from textwrap import dedent
import timeit

N = 10  # Number of executions of each "algorithm"
R = 3  # number of Repeations of executions

# common setup for all algorithms (not timed)
setup = dedent("""
    import itertools
    import gc
    import random

    try:
        xrange
    except NameError:
        xrange = range

    random.seed(0)
    n = 1000000  # number of elements in each list
    A = [random.randrange(1<<30) for _ in xrange(n)]
    B = [random.randrange(1<<30) for _ in xrange(n)]
    C = [random.randrange(1<<30) for _ in xrange(n)]

    # gc.enable()  # to (re)enable garbage collection if desired
""")

algorithms = {
    "set(A+B+C)": dedent("""
        s = set(A+B+C)
    """),

    "set(A); s.update(B); s.update(C)": dedent("""
        s = set(A); s.update(B); s.update(C)
    """),

    "set(itertools.chain(A,B,C))": dedent("""
        s = set(itertools.chain(A,B,C))
        """),

    "set(A).update(B,C)": dedent("""
        s = set(A).update(B,C)
        """),
}

# execute and time algorithms, collecting results
timings = [
    (label,
     min(timeit.repeat(algorithms[label], setup=setup, repeat=R, number=N)),
    ) for label in algorithms
]

print('fastest to slowest execution speeds (Python {}.{}.{})\n'.format(
        *sys.version_info[:3]),
        '  ({:,d} executions, best of {:d} repetitions)\n'.format(N, R))

longest = max(len(timing[0]) for timing in timings)  # length of longest label
ranked = sorted(timings, key=lambda t: t[1])  # ascending sort by execution time
fastest = ranked[0][1]
for timing in ranked:
    print("{:>{width}} : {:9.6f} secs, rel speed {:4.2f}x, {:6.2f}% slower".
            format(timing[0], timing[1], round(timing[1]/fastest, 2),
                   round((timing[1]/fastest - 1) * 100, 2), width=longest))
```