# Union of 2 list's

Tags: python, list

I have 2 list's in the following form:

```
  list1 = [["abc",45,48],["def",13,16]]
  list2 = [["efgh",67,71],["def",13,16]]
```

How can I find the union of these 2 lists?

Required output:

```
  union_list = [["abc",45,48],["def",13,16],["efgh",67,71]]
```

If this helps: As you can see, the `list[0][1]` and `list[0][2]` are `integers`, we can typecast it to a `string` if necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic Way to Create Union of All Values Contained in Multiple Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151517/pythonic-way-to-create-union-of-all-values-contained-in-multiple-lists)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [set.union](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), i.e, you can  map both lists to list of tuples and then convert them to sets so that you can call the `union` method:

```
u_set = set(map(tuple, list1)).union(map(tuple, list2))

# {('abc', 45, 48), ('def', 13, 16), ('efgh', 67, 71)}
```

---

To convert them back to lists:

```
list(map(list, u_set))
# [['def', 13, 16], ['efgh', 67, 71], ['abc', 45, 48]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set comprehension. Since list are un-hashable however, `tuple()`'s must be used instead.

```
>>> list1 = [["abc",45,48],["def",13,16]]
>>> list2 = [["efgh",67,71],["def",13,16]]
>>> {tuple(sublist) for sublist in list1 + list2}
set([('def', 13, 16), ('efgh', 67, 71), ('abc', 45, 48)])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
[list(x) for x in unique_everseen(tuple(y) for y in chain(list1, list2))]
```

`unique_everseen()` can be found in the documentation of module [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools). Conversion to tuple is necessary because the list type is not hashable.

Comment: `chain()` is _also_ found in the `itertools` library. It is usually a good idea to show the functions you import rather than just using them. Also, a link to the documentation of each function wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @leaf I added a link to itertools documentation. Notice that unique_everseen is not included in itertools, it is documented as a (useful) recipe.